# How can I show diameter of subset is less then diameter of superset?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

I know it should be a basic proof but I have stuck. I cannot obtain inequality exactly.

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. If $A,B \subseteq X$ with $A \subseteq B$ then prove that $\delta A \le \delta B$

$\delta A = sup\{ d(a_1,a_2) : a_1,a_2 \in A\}$ and $\delta B = sup\{ d(b_1,b_2) : b_1,b_2 \in B\}$

From supremum axioms

i) $d(a_1,a_2) \le \delta A$ and $d(b_1,b_2) \le \delta B$

ii) $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$ $\exists a_{\epsilon_1}, a_{\epsilon_2} \in A$ such that $d(a_{\epsilon_1}, a_{\epsilon_2}) + \epsilon \ge \delta A $

and  $\exists b_{\epsilon_1}, b_{\epsilon_2} \in B$ such that $d(b_{\epsilon_1}, b_{\epsilon_2}) + \epsilon \ge \delta B $

Since $a_1, a_2 \in B$ at the same time $d(a_1,a_2)$ must be less then $\delta B$. How should I do for proof in the easiest way? I think there are some incorrect or unnecessary thing in my writtens. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_1,a_2\in A$. Then since $A\subseteq B$,
$\delta B \ge d(a_1,a_2)$ by definition. Hence $\delta B$ is an upper bound for the set $$\{d(a_1,a_2) : a_1,a_2\in A\}.$$
Since $\delta A$ is the supremum of this set, we have $\delta A \le \delta B$ by the definition of the supremum as the least upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If $A\subseteq B\subseteq {\mathbb R}$, then $\sup A\leq \sup B$.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot use it without proving. If I prove this for using, it takes up space and our papers are limited in exams

Answer (score 0):

Generally,if you have $C \subset D \subset \mathbb{R}$ then $\sup C \le \sup D$.

Let $C= \{ d(x,y) | x,y \in A\}$, $D= \{ d(x,y) | x,y \in B\}$.

We see that $C \subset D$.

Comment: Thanks but as I ve said unfortunately I cannot use it

Comment: Where did you say that you cannot use what???

Comment: I have said above answer’s comment. I cannot use “if $C \subset D$ then $supC \le supD$”. I have to prove it for using because we did not refer it in lecture. And our papers are limited in exams, its proof would take up space although it is short

Comment: It is a little beyond me that $\sup D \ge c$ for all $c$ is OK, but $\sup D \ge \sup C$ is not. In any event, this is what the accepted answer does in the last sentence, so your objection is spurious.